# Invoke Lambda using SNS from Outside Account

Tags: amazon-sns, aws-lambda

I've been following the following blog post from Amazon (Scenario 3: Triggering a Lambda function from an Amazon S3 bucket notification in another account) about authorizing Lambda functions for various uses.  I would like to setup a Lambda function to accept SNS messages from external accounts (external to the acct with the lambda function).

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/easy-authorization-of-aws-lambda-functions/

I was expecting to add the permission to invoke the function remotely as follows:

```
$ aws lambda add-permission \
     --function-name MyFunction \
     --region us-west-2 \
     --statement-id Id-123 \
     --action "lambda:InvokeFunction" \
     --principal sns.amazonaws.com \
     --source-arn arn:aws:sns:::<topic name> \
     --source-account <account number> \
     --profile adminuser
```

I then attempted to go to my SNS topic and set Lambda as the endpoint, and type in the remote ARN for the lambda function in the first account.  This doesn't work so well, as the endpoint expects an arn for a function in the account...

Plan B:
Try creating the subscription via the CLI to circumvent the limitation in the console...

```
 aws sns --profile adminuser \
     --region us-west-2 subscribe 
     --topic-arn arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:<account #>:<topic name> 
     --protocol lambda 
     --notification-endpoint arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:<account id>:function:<lambda function name>
```

Response:
`A client error (AuthorizationError) occurred when calling the Subscribe operation: The account <account id> is not the owner of the lambda function arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:<account id>:function:<function name>`

Has anyone been able to invoke a Lambda Function from a "remote" SNS in another account?  I'm a little stumped as to where I may have gone wrong... Based on the note in the blog post, I fully expected a remote SNS to work:
`Note: Amazon SNS (Simple Notification Service) events sent to Lambda works the same way, with “sns.amazonaws.com” replacing “s3.amazonaws.com” as the principal.`

Comment: Did you find and solution?

Comment: No, still stuck here unfortunately.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can if the provider account authorizes the consumer account that owns the lambda to subscribe to the SNS topic. This is can be done in the "Edit topic policy" under the [topics page](https://console.aws.amazon.com/sns/v2/home#/topics).

Here's a summary of the steps to allow a lambda to listen to an SNS topic from an external account:

1. Consumer account creates lambda,
2. Consumer account adds event source to lambda in AWS console by specifying the provider's SNS topic ARN (don't worry about error messages here),
3. Provider account adds SNS subscription permissions to a consumer IAM account created in the third-party's AWS account (done via "edit topic policy" mentioned above),
4. Consumer uses the IAM account from step 2 to add subscription to provider account using AWS CLI.

Example command that worked for me previously for step 4:

```
aws sns subscribe --topic-arn <provider_sns_arn> --protocol lambda --notification-endpoint <consumer_lambda_arn> --profile consumer-IAM-account
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the outlined steps.  Out of curiosity, are there any ways to automatically confirm the subscription as well, or does that logic need to be handled within the lambda function?

Comment: You don't need to confirm the subscription. It is ready for testing after `aws sns subscribe` command has been run.

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing...but the provider SNS topic is in us-west-2 and the target Lambda function in us-east-1 in another account. Could that solution work ?

Comment: @KostasDemiris The SNS topic ARN in this example from the documentation seems to include the region. Thus, I suspect it will work.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sns/subscribe.html

Comment: @KostasDemiris: It's possible to have an SNS topic trigger a Lambda function cross account + cross region using the instructions mentioned in Daniel's accepted answer. Remember to make sure that the last 'aws sns subscribe' command is being executed in the same region as the SNS topic (and not the region the Lambda function is in), otherwise you'll get an error: 'Invalid Topic Arn'.

Answer (score 4):

Was having the similar requirement today. In summary there are 3 steps. Let's assume `111111111` is the producer account which has the SNS topic and `2222222222` is the consumer which has the lambda, and

1. Allowing the Lambda function to subscribe to the topic

   ```sh
   aws sns --profile SNS_Owner_Profile add-permission \  
         --topic-arn "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:111111111:your-sns-top" \  
         --label "AllowCrossAccountSns" \  
         --aws-account-id "2222222222" \  
         --action-name "Receive" "Subscribe"
   ```
2. allow the topic to invoke the Lambda function,

   ```sh
   aws lambda --profile Lambda_Owner_Profile add-permission \                                                                                                                     
         --function-name "your-lambda-function" \  
         --statement-id "allowCrossAccountSNS" \  
         --principal "sns.amazonaws.com" \  
         --action "lambda:InvokeFunction" \  
         --source-arn "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:111111111:your-sns-top"
   ```
3. subscribe the lambda function to the topic.

   ```sh
   aws sns --profile Lambda_Owner_Profile subscribe \                                                                                                                          
         --topic-arn "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:111111111:your-sns-top" \  
         --protocol "lambda" \  
         --notification-endpoint "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:2222222222:function:your-lambda-function"
   ```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem.  The error is because you are calling the SNS subscribe function from the account that owns the SNS topic.  While this seems logical and is how you would normally do it, AWS expects you to do it the other way around when it comes to cross-account access - you have to call the SNS subscribe function from the account that owns the Lambda function.

Answer (score 1):

In AWS Lambda Developer Guide there is a [tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sns-create-x-account-permissions.html)  where AWS CLI commands are used to set up an invocation of a Lambda function from SNS that belongs to another account.

The procedure is quite similar as the procedure in the accepted answer. The subscription doesn't have to be confirmed. It was ready for testing right after `aws sns subscribe` command.